# update manager error-Failed to download repository information

Tags: updates, repository, downloads

When I run update manager, Ii get following error.

[image]

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, 64 bit.
I am new to Ubuntu please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that this repository does not have packages for your version of Ubuntu (precise). Take a look at http://ppa.launchpad.net/crebs/ppa/ubuntu/dists/.

You need to remove this repository from your /etc/apt/sources.list file.

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Find the lines that contain "crebs". They should look like

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/crebs/ppa/ubuntu jaunty main
```

(or something like this). and put a `#` (hash) in front of each of them:

```
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/crebs/ppa/ubuntu jaunty main
```

Repository is now disabled. Save the file, exit the editor and in a terminal, run

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

(there is also a GUI way of doing that via software sources or something similar from Ubuntu dash, but I don't remember where it sits)

Comment: Please note that precise is also using the directory `/etc/apt/sources.d/` to manage repositories. Therefore the entry could also be in a file inside the named directory.

Comment: Yes (and not only precise). My guess is, however, that it is in sources.list.

Comment: Software Sources (Software and Updates in 13.04) is the GUI location to 'uncheck' a repository.

Comment: Update Manager (Settings) is the GUI location to 'Uncheck' a repository, in Ubuntu 12.04(precise).